# Prove $3^{2n+1} + 2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n\ge0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Expanding the equation out gives

$(3^{2n}\times3)+(2^n\times2^2) \equiv 0\pmod{7}$

Is this correct? I'm a little hazy on my index laws.

Not sure if this is what I need to do? Am I on the right track?

Comment: See also: 
[Show that $7\mid(3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2})$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/810063),
[How to prove that $2^{n+2}+3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by 7 using induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1286522),
[Find all $n$ such that $3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1604280),
[Prove by induction: $2^{n+2} +3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2427747),
[Prove that $3^{2n-1} + 2^{n+1}$ is always a multiple of $7$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2681223),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial calculation can lead to an answer.

Our expression is equal to $3(9^n)+4(2^n)$. Note that $9\equiv 2\pmod{7}$, and therefore $9^n\equiv 2^n \pmod{7}$. It follows that
$$3(9^n)+4(2^n)\equiv 3(2^n)+4(2^n)=7(2^n)\equiv 0\pmod{7}.$$

Comment: No disrespect to Marvis' excellent and elaborate explanation but this short answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$\rm \begin{eqnarray} {\bf Hint}\ \ \ a_{n\!+\!1}\!=2\,a_{n},\ b_{n\!+\!1}\!=9\,b_{n}\:\Rightarrow\: a_{n\!+\!1}\!+ b_{n\!+\!1} &\: =\: &\rm  2\ (\ a_{n}\!+b_{n}) + 7\,b_{n} \\
\rm hence\quad 7\mid a_{n\!+\!1}\!+ b_{n\!+\!1} &\rm \, if\, &\rm 7\mid a_{n}\!+b_{n}\end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$3^{2n+1} = 3^{2n} \cdot 3^1 = 3 \cdot 9^n$$ and $$2^{n+2} = 4 \cdot 2^n$$
Note that $9^{3k} \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ and $2^{3k} \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$.

If $n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then $$3 \cdot 9^n + 4 \cdot 2^n \equiv (3+4) \pmod{7} \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$$
If $n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, then $$3 \cdot 9^n + 4 \cdot 2^n \equiv (3 \cdot 9 + 4 \cdot 2) \pmod{7} \equiv 35 \pmod{7} \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$$
If $n \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, then $$3 \cdot 9^n + 4 \cdot 2^n \equiv (3 \cdot 9^2 + 4 \cdot 2^2) \pmod{7} \equiv 259 \pmod{7} \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$$

**EDIT**
What you have written can be generalized a bit. In general, $$(x^2 + x + 1) \vert \left((x+1)^{2n+1} + x^{n+2} \right)$$
The case you are interested in is when $x=2$.

The proof follows immediately from the factor theorem. Note that $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are roots of $(x^2 + x + 1)$.

If we let $f(x) = (x+1)^{2n+1} + x^{n+2}$, then $$f(\omega) = (\omega+1)^{2n+1} + \omega^{n+2} = (-\omega^2)^{2n+1} + \omega^{n+2} = \omega^{4n} (-\omega^2) + \omega^{n+2} = \omega^{n+2} \left( 1 - \omega^{3n}\right) = 0$$
Similarly, $$f(\omega^2) = (\omega^2+1)^{2n+1} + \omega^{2(n+2)} = (-\omega)^{2n+1} + \omega^{2n+4} = -\omega^{2n+1} + \omega^{2n+1} \omega^3 = -\omega^{2n+1} + \omega^{2n+1} = 0$$