# Show that $7\mid(3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2})$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that the following is true for every $n∈ℕ$:
>
> $$7\mid(3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}).$$

I've noticed
$$3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2} =3^{2n} \cdot 3+2^{n} \cdot 4.$$

Any suggestions how to continue from there to get something like $7k$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? :)

Comment: Two options: Induction, or use $3^{2n}=9^n$ and modular arithmetic.

Comment: Hint: if $a \equiv b (\text{mod } c)$, then we'll have $a^n \equiv b^n (\text{mod } c)$, and $9 \equiv 2 (\text{mod } 7)$. Or you can try proof by induction, it should work too. :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews There is also a method using recurrence relations which can be used to find the sequence $k_n$

Comment: @MarkBennet What is the difference between recurrence and induction?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Probably less than I thought when I wrote the comment - you need an induction anyway. The recurrence makes the induction very easy to see, but hides the machinery which makes it work so it isn't so elementary and is a bit of a cheat (I think). But the method does make it obvious that divisibility persists in general, rather than each instance being a special case.

Comment: See also:
[Prove $3^{2n+1} + 2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n\ge0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/233937)
[How to prove that $2^{n+2}+3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by 7 using induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1286522),
[Find all $n$ such that $3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1604280),
[Prove by induction: $2^{n+2} +3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2427747),
[Prove that $3^{2n-1} + 2^{n+1}$ is always a multiple of $7$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2681223).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}=3\cdot 9^n + 4\cdot 2^n&=7\cdot 9^n -4(9^n-2^n)\\
&=7\cdot 9^n-4(9-2)(9^{n-1}+9^{n-2}\cdot2+\cdots+2^{n-1})\\
&=7[ 9^n-4(9^{n-1}+9^{n-2}\cdot 2\cdots+2^{n-1})]\end{align}

Which is divisible by $7$

Here is a solution based on congruences,

$$3\cdot 9^n +4\cdot 2^n \equiv 3\cdot 2^n +4\cdot 2^n \equiv 7\cdot 2^n \equiv 0\text{(mod 7)}$$

Comment: Thank you. I was closer to the first method. I tried rewriting $3$ to $(7-4)$ and $4$ to $(7-3)$, whereas I should only rewrite $3$ to $(7-4)$ and leave alone the number $4$. I wonder when I would figure that out on my own.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ \ 7\mid\color{#c00}{3^2}\!\color{#c00}-\!\color{#c00}2,\,\ 7\mid\overbrace{\color{#0a0}{3^{2k+1}}\!\color{#0a0}+\! \color{#0a0}{2^{k+2}}}^{\large P(k)} \Rightarrow\, 7\mid 2(\color{#0a0}{3^{2k+1}\!\!+\!2^{k+2}}) + (\color{#c00}{3^2\!-2})3^{2k+1}\! =\, \overbrace{3^{2k+3}\!+2^{k+3}}^{\large P(k+1)}$

---

**Or** $\!\bmod 7\!:\,\ 3\cdot (\color{#c00}{3^2})^k\!+ 4\cdot 2^k\equiv\, 3\cdot \color{#c00}2^k\! + 4\cdot 2^k\equiv\, 7\cdot 2^k\equiv 0,\, $ by $\,\color{#c00}{3^2\equiv 2}$

The Remark below shows how to  derive the first inductive proof from the second modular proof (it shows the inductive proof is precisely a special case of a proof of the Congruence Product Rule).

---

**Or**, notice $\ 2^2\!+2+1 = 7\ $ so we can apply

**Lemma** $\ \ a^2\!+a+1\mid a^{n+2}+(a+1)^{2n+1}\!  =: b$

**Proof** $\, \ {\rm mod}\,\ a^2\!+a+1\!:\ \color{#0a0}{a(a+1)\equiv -1}$ and $\,\color{#c00}{a^3\equiv 1}\ $ by $\,0\equiv (a\!-\!1)(a^2\!+a+1) = a^3\!-1,\,$

$\quad {\rm so}\,\ \ \  a^{2n+1}b = a^{3n+3} + (\color{#0c0}{a(a+1)})^{2n+1} \equiv\, (\color{#c00}{a^3})^{n+1}\!-1\equiv 0\ $ so $\ b\equiv 0.\ \ \ \bf\small QED$

---

**Or** $\  a\!+\!1\equiv -a^2\Rightarrow\,(a\!+\!1)^{2n+1}\equiv -a^{4n+2}\equiv -a^{n+2}\ $ by $\,(\color{#c00}{a^3})^n\equiv \color{#c00}1^n,\,$ cf. [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242).

---

**Remark** $\ $ Below I explain how the first *explicit* inductive proof is a special case of the second congruence arithmetic proof, which boils down to $\color{#0a0}{(-1)^{2n+1}\equiv -1}\,$ and $\color{#c00}{1^{n+1}\equiv 1},\,$ both of which have *trivial* inductive proofs (a special case of the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762060/242) inductive proof).

Here is  the inductive step $\,P(k)\,\Rightarrow\,P(k\!+\!1)\,$ written in *intuitive* congruence arithmetical form

$$\begin{eqnarray} {\rm mod}\ 7\!:\qquad \color{#c00}{3^{\large 2}} &\equiv&\, \color{#c00}2\\[.2em]
\times\qquad\quad  \color{#0a0}{3^{\large 2k+1}}&\equiv&\, \color{#0a0}{-2^{\large k+2}},\quad\:\!\ {\rm i.e.}\ \ \ P(k)_{\phantom{|}}\\
\hline
\Rightarrow\quad \ \color{#c00}{3^{\large 2^{\Large\phantom{|}}}}\: \color{#0a0}{3^{\large 2k+1}} &\equiv&\, \color{#c00}2 (\color{#0a0}{- 2^{\large k+2}})\\[.2em] 
{\rm i.e.}\quad 3^{\large 2(k+1)+1} &\equiv&\, {-}\!2^{\large k+3},\ \ \ \ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ P(k\!+\!1)\\
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

by the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762060/242) $\ A\equiv a,\ B\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, AB\equiv ab.\, $ If congruence arithmetic is unfamiliar it can be eliminated by unwinding the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762060/242) of the Product Rule (or, more conceptually, by using an equivalent [Divisibility Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242)), yielding a proof in *divisibility* language

$\quad \begin{eqnarray}  0\,\equiv\, \color{#c00}{A}&\color{#c00}-&\color{#c00}a, &&\ \color{#0a0}{B}&\color{#0a0}-& \color{#0a0}b &\Rightarrow& \qquad AB\ -\ ab &=& a\ \ (\color{#0a0}{\  B\ \ -\ \ b}\ ) &+& (\color{#c00}{A-a})B\,\equiv\, 0\\[.2em] 
7\,\mid\, \color{#c00}{3^2}&\color{#c00}-&\color{#c00}2, && \color{#0a0}{3^{2k+1}}\!&\color{#0a0}+&\! \color{#0a0}{2^{k+2}} &\Rightarrow& 7\mid 3^{2k+3}\!+2^{k+3}\! &=& 2(\color{#0a0}{3^{2k+1}\!+2^{k+2}}) &+& (\color{#c00}{3^2\!-2})3^{2k+1}\phantom{I^{I^I}} \\
\end{eqnarray}$

The prior is precisely the common inductive proof that is usually **pulled out of hat like magic**, without any intuitive motivation. We can employ further congruence arithmetic to make it even more obvious than above. Notice $P(k)\,$ is $\,3\cdot 9^k\equiv 3\cdot  2^k\,$ (by $\:\!{-}4\equiv 3),\,$ so $P(k\!+\!1)$ arises simply by scaling it by $\,9\equiv 2\ $ to get $\, P(k\!+\!1)\!:\: 3\cdot 9^{k+1}\!\equiv 3\cdot 2^{k+1}.\, $ Even more clearly, by dividing by $\,3\cdot 2^k\,$  we see that $P(k)\:\!$ is equivalent to $\,(9/2)^k\equiv 1.\,$ But $\,9\equiv 2\,$ so $\,9/2\equiv 1,\,$ so the induction proof boils down to the *trivial* induction that $1^k\equiv 1,\,$ which is a trivial special case of the inductive proof of the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762060/242). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242) and [this list](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A242%20induction%20magic%20hat) for more examples like this.

Similarly, many inductions can be transformed into such standard or trivial inductions. Hence it is well-worth the effort to spend some time looking for such innate structure. This is especially true for divisibility problems, since transforming to congruence form allow us to exploit our well-honed *arithmetical* intuition, which is *much* stronger than our intuition on divisibility relation calculus.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $2 \equiv 3^2 \pmod 7$, therefore
$$
3^{2n+1} + 2^{n+2} \equiv 3^{2n+1} + 3^{2n+4} \equiv 3^{2n+1} \cdot 28 \pmod 7,
$$
and that is of course divisible by $7$.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}=3\times\color{red}9^n+4\times2^n\equiv3\times\color{red}2^n+4\times2^n=7\times2^n\equiv0\mod7$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that a sequence with form $u_n=a\cdot 9^n+b\cdot 2^n$ satisfies a linear recurrence with auxiliary equation $$(x-9)(x-2)=0$$ so that $$u_{n+1}=11u_n-18u_{n-1}$$

Hence if $7|u_n \& 7|u_{n-1}$ then $7|u_{n+1}$. We have $u_0=7, u_1=35$ both divisible by $7$, so with a base case established we are done by induction.

If $u_n=7k_n$, then $k_n$ satisfies the same recurrence with $k_0=1, k_1=5$

Answer (score 0):

Just surprised that the very crude induction method with $u_n=3\cdot 9^n+4\cdot 2^n$ hasn't been posted yet - it goes $$u_{n+1} = 3\cdot 9^{n+1}+4\cdot 2^{n+1}=7\cdot3\cdot 9^n+2\cdot 3\cdot 9^n+2\cdot 4\cdot 2^n=7\cdot 3\cdot 9^n+2\cdot u_n$$ which is divisible by $7$ if $u_n$ is divisible by $7$. Base case is $u_0=7$. It depends on the fact that $9-2$ is divisible by $7$.