# $13\mid4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How can I prove that $4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2}$ is always divisible by 13?

Comment: **Hint:** Try using induction to prove the statement.

Comment: I tried induction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2}=16^n\cdot 4+3^n\cdot 9\\16^n\cdot4+3^n\cdot 9\equiv3^n\cdot4+3^n\cdot 9\pmod {13}\\3^n(4+9)\equiv3^n\cdot13\equiv0\pmod{13}$$
This can also be solved with induction,for $n=0$
$$4+3^2=13$$
Assume it holds for $n=k$
$$4^{2k+1}+3^{k+2}$$
Prove it holds for $n=k+1$
$$4^{2k+3}+3^{k+3}=16\cdot4^{2k+1}+3\cdot3^{k+2}=16\cdot4^{2k+1}+16\cdot3^{k+2}-13\cdot3^{k+2}=16(4^{2k+1}+3^{k+2})-13\cdot3^{k+2}$$
by the inductive hypothesis $4^{2k+1}+3^{k+2}$ is divisible by $13$ because of that the whole expression is

Comment: Remark that the inductive proof is just the congruence proof unwound, i.e. it arises by inlining the proof of the Congruence Product Rule. This is explained at length in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/810073/242)

Answer (score 4):

You can use congruence:
$$
4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2}\equiv 4(16^n)+9(3^n) \equiv 4(16^n)+(13-4)(3^n) \equiv 4(16^n-3^n) \equiv 4(3^n-3^n) \equiv 0\ (\text{mod }13).
$$

Also you can prove it directly:
$$
4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2} = 4(16^n-3^n)+(13)(3^n) = 13[4(16^{n-1}+16^{n-2}3+16^{n-3}3^2+\ldots+3^{n-1})+3^n]
$$
which proves that $4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2}$ is dividable by $13$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Specialize $\, a = 3\,$ below. $ $ See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/810073/242) for an inductive proof and further discussion.

**Theorem** $\quad a^2\!+a+1\mid a^{n+2}+(a\!+\!1)^{2n+1}\!  =: b$

**Proof** $\, \ {\rm mod}\,\ a^2\!+a+1\!:\ \color{#0a0}{a(a\!+\!1)\equiv -1}$ and $\,\color{#c00}{a^3\equiv 1}\ $ by $\,0\equiv (a\!-\!1)(a^2\!+a+1) = a^3\!-1,\,$ so

$\qquad\quad\! a^{2n+1}b = a^{3n+3} + (\color{#0c0}{a(a\!+\!1)})^{2n+1} \equiv\, (\color{#c00}{a^3})^{n+1}\!-1\equiv 0$

Thus $\,\ a^{2n+1}b \equiv 0\ $ times $\,a^{n-1}\,$ yields $\ b \equiv (\color{#c00}{a^3})^n b\equiv 0\ \ $ **QED**

Answer (score 1):

By induction: the base case $n=0$ is obvious. Assume true for $n=k$, so all that remains to show is for $n=k+1$.

Since we know the claim is true for $n=k$:

$$A_k : = 4^{2k+1}+3^{k+2}$$

is divisible by 13. We proceed by showing that $A_{k+1} - 3 A_k$ is divisible by 13, from which the claim follows:
$$= 4^2 \cdot4^{2k+1} + 3\cdot3^{k+2} - 3(4^{2k+1} + 3^{k+2}) = 4^{2k+1}\cdot 13$$

So we are done.

Comment: This is *equivalent* (a rearrangement) of the common inductive proof in KingW3's $2014$ answer. They prove $\!\bmod 13\!:\ A_{k+1} \equiv 16 A_k\ (\equiv  3 A_k$ as in your proof). All these common inductive proofs are special cases of a standard proof of the Congruence Product Rule - as I explain at length [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/810073/242). It's best for site health not to duplicate prior answers (esp. for FAQs like this).

Answer (score 0):

let's using mod function
$$ \left(4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2} \right)\text{ mod }13=\left((4-13)^{2n+1}+3^{n+2} \right)\text{ mod }13=\left(-3^{4n+2}+3^{n+2} \right)\text{ mod }13 $$
$$ \because \text{  }3^3\text{ mod }13=1 \text{  }\therefore\text{  }3^n\text{ mod }13=3^{n\text{ mod }3} $$
$$ \to \left(-3^{4n+2}+3^{n+2} \right)\text{ mod }13 =\left(-3^{n+2}+3^{n+2} \right)\text{ mod }13=0$$
$$ \therefore 4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2}  \text{   is divisible by  }13$$