# show by induction that $4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2}$ is divisible by $13$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, natural-numbers

i'm stuck in this problem, anyone can give me a hint, please?

"Show by induction that $4^{2n+1} + 3^{n+2}$ is divisible by $13$

In my attempt i got the expression

$$4^{2}\cdot 4^{2n+1} + 3\cdot 3^{n+2}$$

but i can't go more, any suggestion is thankful.

Comment: $ 4 \cdot 16^n + 9 \cdot 3^n$   and $16 \equiv 3 \pmod {13} $

Comment: suggestion:  replace $4^2$ with $13+3$

Comment: cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859523/13-mid42n13n2)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner excelent! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
4^{2}\cdot 4^{2n+1} + 3\cdot 3^{n+2}= 16(4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2}) -13 \times 3^{n+2}.
\end{eqnarray*}