# Prove that for every integer $n \geq 0$, the number $4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2}$ is a multiple of 13.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Prove that for every integer $n \geq 0$,
 the number $4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2}$ is a multiple of 13.

Comment: But what did you try?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/810073/242) for a detailed explanation of the arithmetical essence of the induction.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we have $$4^{2n+1}+3^{n+2}=16^n\cdot 4+3^n\cdot 9\equiv 3^n\cdot 4+3^n\cdot 9\equiv 3^n\cdot 13$$