# Find all $n$ such that $3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find all $n$ such that

$3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$

Prove that your answer is correct

So I am not allowed to use mods,  as is a calculus question, I have tried by induction but can't get to prove that it works for $k+1$, by multiplying the equation by powers of $2$ and $3$.

Thank you for your help

Comment: See also:
[Prove $3^{2n+1} + 2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n\ge0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/233937)
[Show that $7\mid(3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2})$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/810063),
[How to prove that $2^{n+2}+3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by 7 using induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1286522),
[Prove by induction: $2^{n+2} +3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2427747),
[Prove that the number $3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3795659).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{split}
3^{2(k+1)+1} + 2^{(k+1)+2} &= 9\cdot 3^{2k+1} + 2\cdot 2^{k+2}\\
&= 7 \cdot 3^{2k+1} + 2 (3^{2k+1} + 2^{k+2}). 
\end{split}$$

Comment: I have just done it

Answer (score 2):

$3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n$:

$
3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}=\\
=3\cdot 9^n+4\cdot 2^n\\
=3\cdot (7+2)^n+(7-3)\cdot 2^n\\
=3(7a+2^n)+7\cdot2^n-3\cdot 2^n\\
=7(3a+2^n)
$

where I have used the binomial theorem for getting $(7+2)^n=7a+2^n$.

Comment: You can shorten it a bit. $$3\cdot 9^n+4\cdot 2^n=3\cdot (7+2)^n+4\cdot 2^n=3(7a+2^n)+4\cdot 2^n=7(3a+2^n)$$

Comment: @user236182, nicely spotted!

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n=3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ then you will find that $A_{n+1}=11A_n-18A_{n-1}$

Rationale: If $u_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n$ it is easy to check that $u_{n+1}=(\alpha+\beta)u_n-\alpha\beta u_{n-1}$.

Set $\alpha = 3^2=9, \beta=2$.

You need two consecutive values to ensure the persistence of the factor $7$ (you could use $n=-1$ even though the value involves fractions), which makes it less attractive in some ways than the induction arguments with a single base case. However, this can also used to construct further examples of persistence, and is quick if you are doing multiple questions of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

You're not allowed to use mod, but here's a proof using mod:

$$3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}=3\cdot 9^{n}+4\cdot 2^n$$

$$\equiv 3\cdot 2^n+4\cdot 2^n\equiv 7\cdot 2^n\equiv 0\pmod{7}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just another way:

Inductive hypothesis: $3^{2n+1} = 7k - 2^{n+2}$

Inductive step:
$$3^{2n+3} + 2^{n+3} = 3^2 * 3^{2n+1} + 2 * 2^{n+2} $$

$=3^2(7k - 2^{n+2})+2*2^{n+2}$

$=7k(3^2) - 3^2*2^{n+2} + 2* 2^{n+2}$

$=7k(3^2) + 2^{n+2}(-3^2+2)$

$=7k(3^2) -7*(2^{n+2})$

Both terms are divisible by 7

Comment: Thank you! What tool do you use to write on latex?

Comment: Enter your equation within Dollar ($) signs. So start with a dollar sign, enter equation and end with a dollar sign.

Comment: Great it seems easy enough

Answer (score -1):

1. Setting $n=1$, we get $$3^{2\cdot 1+1}+2^{1+2}=35$$ above number $35$ is divisible by $7$ hence it holds for $n=1$
2. Assume the number $3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$ for $n=k$ then $$3^{2k+1}+2^{k+2}=7\lambda \tag 1$$
3. Setting $n=k+1$, we get $$3^{2k+2+1}+2^{k+1+2}$$
   $$=9\cdot 3^{2k+1}+2\cdot 2^{k+1}$$
   $$=9\cdot 3^{2k+1}+9\cdot 2^{k+1}-7\cdot 2^{k+1}$$
   $$=9(3^{2k+1}+2^{k+1})-7\cdot 2^{k+1}$$
   setting the value from (1), 
   $$=9(7\lambda)-7\cdot 2^{k+1}$$
   $$=7(9\lambda-2^{k+1})$$

since, $(9\lambda-2^{k+1})$ is some integer hence the number $7(9\lambda-2^{k+1})$ is divisible by $7$

hence the number $(3^{2n+1}+2^{n+1})$ is divisible by $7$ for all integers $n\ge 1$

Answer (score -1):

Little Hint: 
Note that from little Fermat's theorem that $2^6\equiv 1$ and $3^6\equiv 1$. Then the remainders of $3$ $\pmod 7$ are $$3,2,6,4,5$$ while the remainders of $2$ $\pmod 7$ are $$2,4,1$$ If $n=1$, $2^3\equiv 1$ and $3^3\equiv 6$......

Comment: The OP said  mod is not allowed.