# Find all integers $n$ such that $7 \mid (5^n -1).$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all integers $n$ such that $7 \mid (5^n +1).$

From flt, $5^6\equiv 1 \pmod 7.$ but how to proceed from here?

Comment: You only have to find the smallest positive integer $\ k\ $ with $\ 5^k\equiv 1\mod 7\ $, which is $\ 6\ $. The solutions are then exactly the multiples of $\ k\ $, in this case the multiples of $\ 6\ $. This $\ k\ $ is also called the order of $\ 5\ $ modulo $\ 7\ $ , and is denoted by $\ k=ord_5(7)\ $

Comment: For (almost) the same question see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604280/find-all-n-such-that-32n12n2-is-divisible-by-7).

Comment: Correction : The notation here is $\ k=ord_7(5)\ $

Comment: the question says (5^n + 1). I have understood for minus. But how Should I proceed with a plus sign?

Comment: The question says + but the title says -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I: For minus sign

$5^n-1={5^3}^{(\frac{n}{3})}-1$

$={(126-1)}^{(\frac{n}{3})}-1$

$={(7*18-1)}^{(\frac{n}{3})}-1$

$={(-1)}^{(\frac{n}{3})}-1$

For it to be zero, $\frac{n}{3}$=even i.e. 2k

so n should be of the form 6k

II: With a plus sign

$5^n+1={5^3}^{(\frac{n}{3})}+1$

$={(126-1)}^{(\frac{n}{3})}+1$

$={(7*18-1)}^{(\frac{n}{3})}+1$

$={(-1)}^{(\frac{n}{3})}+1$

With a plus sign for it to be zero $\frac{n}{3}$= odd i.e. 2k-1

so n should be of the form n=3(2k-1)

Comment: thanks. But the question is 5^n +1. can you please solve for the plus sign?

Comment: @Diwakar Changed it to include plus also