# Prove that $3^{2n-1} + 2^{n+1}$ is always a multiple of $7$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I'm trying to prove the following statement:
$P(n) = 3^{2n-1} + 2^{n+1}$ is always a multiple of $7$  $\forall n\geq1$.
I want to use induction, so the base case is $P(1) = 7$ so that's okay.

Now I need to prove that if $P(n)$ is true then $P(n+1)$ is true.
So there exists a $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$ 3^{2n-1} + 2^{n+1} = 7d $$
From this I need to say that there exists a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$ 3^{2n+1} + 2^{n+2} = 7k $$
With a little algebraic manipulation, I have managed to say:
$$ 2 \cdot 3^{2n+1} + 9 \cdot 2^{n+2} = 7\cdot(18d) $$
But now I am stuck. How should I keep going?

Comment: See also: [Prove $3^{2n+1} + 2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n\ge0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/233937), [How to prove that $2^{n+2}+3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by 7 using induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1286522), [Find all $n$ such that $3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1604280), [Prove by induction: $2^{n+2} +3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2427747), [Show that $7\mid(3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2})$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/810063)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If

$$2 \cdot 3^{2n+1} + 9 \cdot 2^{n+2} = 7\cdot 18d$$

Then

$$2 \cdot 3^{2n+1} + 2 \cdot 2^{n+2} = 7\cdot 18d - 7 \cdot 2^{n+2}$$

And we conclude

$$3^{2n+1} + 2^{n+2} = \frac{7(18d - 2^{n+2})}{2} = 7(9d - 2^{n+1})$$

Answer (score 2):

$3^{2n-1}+2^{n+1}=9^n3^{-1}+2^n2\equiv 2^n3^{-1}+2^n2=5\times2^n+2\times 2^n=7\times2^n\equiv0 \pmod7 $ since $3^{-1}\equiv5 \pmod7$

Answer (score 2):

$$2\equiv 9$$
$$2\equiv 3^2$$

$$2^{n+1}\equiv 3^{2n+2} $$

$$3^{2n-1}+3^{2n+2}=3^{2n-1}(1+27)$$

$$=4.7.3^{2n-1} $$

Done

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to extract the $n$-th case from $(n+1)$-th case. To show it for $n+1$:
$$\begin{align}&3^{2(n+1)-1}+2^{(n+1)+1}= \\
&3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}= \\ 
&9\cdot 3^{2n-1}+2\cdot 2^{n+1}= \\
&2(3^{2n-1}+2^{n+1})+7\cdot 3^{2n-1}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

We can proof it by induction; it is clear that $P(n)$ hold for $n=1$  and we Assume that it hold for $n$ so 
$$2^{n+1}=7k - 3^{2n-1}$$
Show it for $n+1$ 
$$ 3^{2(n+1)-1} + 2^{(n+1)+1} = 3^{2n+1} + 2.2^{n+1}=  3^{2n+1}+2(7k - 3^{2n-1})=   3^{2n+1} + 2.3^{2n-1}+14k = (9-2).3^{2n-1}+14k= 7(3^{2n-1}+2k)$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, suppose $3^{2n-1}+2^{n+1}= 7x$.

Then, $x=\frac17\left(3^{2n-1}+2^{n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{21}\left(3^{2n}+6(2^{n})\right)=\frac{1}{21}\left(9^{n}+6(2^{n})\right)\equiv 0 \pmod3$

Now, $9\equiv 2 \pmod7\Rightarrow9^n\equiv 2^n \pmod3$, $6\equiv -1 \pmod7$ and hence, $6\cdot2^n\equiv (-1)\cdot2^n\pmod7$

Therefore, $9^{n}+6(2^{n})\equiv 0 \pmod7$, because $9^{n}\equiv 2^n \pmod7$ and $6\cdot2^{n}\equiv -2^n \pmod7$

Therefore, since $9^{n}+6(2^{n})\equiv 0 \pmod3$, $9^{n}+6(2^{n})\equiv 0 \pmod{21}$, hence $\frac{1}{21}\left(9^{n}+6(2^{n})\right)=\frac{1}{7}\left(3^{2n-1}+2^{n+1}\right)$ is an integer.