# Prove that this number is divisible by 7

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, integers

Without using induction, how can it be proved that 7 divides $3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$?
I tried to expand it using $\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=1+x+..+x^n$ but I had no success.
It would be great if more than one proof is provided.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It would be great if even one attempt were provided! What have you tried?

Comment: I have edited . Great sense humor ahaha @TokenToucan.

Comment: Any number other than zero divides zero!

Comment: In plain language, the quantity under consideration is zero modulo 7!

Comment: See also: [Prove $3^{2n+1} + 2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n\ge0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/233937), [How to prove that $2^{n+2}+3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by 7 using induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1286522), [Find all $n$ such that $3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1604280), [Prove by induction: $2^{n+2} +3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2427747), [Show that $7\mid(3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2})$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/810063).

Comment: A general advice is try to search whether the question isn't already answered on the site. For example, you can try [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%243%5E%7B2n%2B1%7D%2B2%5E%7Bn%2B2%7D%24&p=1) or [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=$%7B7%5Cmid%203%5E%7B2n%2B1%7D%2B2%5E%7Bn%2B2%7D%7D$). For more details, see: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2})x^n = \frac{3}{1-9x}+\frac{4}{1-2x} = \frac{ \color{red}{7} (1-6x)}{(1-9x)(1-2x)}. 
\end{eqnarray*}
This function clearly has integer coefficients
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \frac{  (1-6x)}{(1-9x)(1-2x)}=(1-6x) \left( 1 +9x+81x^2+ \cdots \right) \left( 1 +2x+4x^2+ \cdots \right). 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Do not you mean $\frac{2}{1-2x}$ instead of $\frac{4}{1-2x}$?

Comment: It is perfect... but  how can I deduce that 7 divides each term of the series?

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Thanks @Gio $ \ddot \smile$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Simplify $3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ modulo $7$, using the fact that $3^{2n+1}=3\cdot 3^{2n}$ and $3^2\equiv2\pmod7$.

Comment: Was just about to write this too

Comment: for this method, would you have to do case work?

Comment: @CSquared: No; it’s a one-line proof.

Answer (score 0):

$3^{2n + 1} + 2^{n+2} = 3\cdot 3^{2n} + 2^2\cdot 2^n = 3\cdot(9)^n + 4\cdot s2^n\equiv 3\cdot(2)^n + 4\times 2^n = 7\cdot 2^n\equiv 0\pmod 7$.

Answer (score 0):

$3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}=3\times9^n+4\times2^n=7\times2^n+3\times(9^n-2^n)$

$=7\times2^n+3\times(9-2)(9^{n-1}+\cdots+2^{n-1})=\color{red}7\times2^n+3\times\color{red}7(9^{n-1}+\cdots+2^{n-1})$